# ¿Cómo funciona crear dos variables simultaneamente?

Tags: python, funciones, fibonacci

Estaba aprendiendo a definir funciones, cuando me encontré con este código que imprime la serie de Fibonacci hasta un límite determinado:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    """Escribe la serie de Fibonacci hasta n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end='" "')
        a, b= b, a+b
    print()
```

Quisiera saber qué valor toma exactamente cada variable y cómo se modifica conforme de ejecuta la función.

Answer (score 0):

Python evalúa las expresiones de izquierda a derecha, pero cuando se evalúa una asignación el lado derecho es evaluado antes. Por lo tanto, cuando hacemos:

```
a, b = 0, 1
```

Lo que se hace es evaluar primero:

```
0, 1
```

Esto es en realidad implícitamente una tupla, es decir, equivale a:

```
(0, 1)
```

Una vez que tenemos dicha tupla creada, se evalúa el lado izquierdo de la expresión:

```
a, b
```

Tenemos por tanto dos identificadores de variables a los que se les asigna una tupla (`a, b = (0, 1)`), el siguiente paso es desempaquetar la tupla y asignar cada identificador al elemento correspondiente de la tupla según su orden:

```
a = 0  # (a = (0, 1)[0])
b = 1  # (b = (0, 1)[1])
```

Esto es muy útil cuando queremos intercambiar el valor de dos variables:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a
2
>>> b
1
```

Tu algoritmo hace uso de esto en:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

que simplemente reasigna el valor de `b` a `a` y `b` pasa a valer `a + b`.  Esta es la base de la sucesión de Fibonacci, cada término es la suma de los dos anteriores. Las variable `a` alamcena siempre el penúltimo termino calculado y `b` el último, para calcular siguiente termino de la sucesión sumamos ambas variables y se lo asignamos a `b`, el valor anterior de `b` ahora es el penúltimo y se le asigna por tanto a `a`, esto lo repetimos cuantas veces queramos.

No solo las tuplas son susceptibles de ser desempaquetadas, podemos desempaquetar cualquier otro iterable:

```
>>> a, b = [2, 5]
>>> a
2
>>> b
5
>>> a, b = (range(7, 9))
>>> a
7
>>> b
8
>>> a, b = {0:4, 1:5}
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
```

Por supuesto que el número de variables a de ser el mismo que elementos tiene el iterable a desempaquetar.